# Convert a double to time point using std chrono library

Tags: c++, epoch, c++-chrono

I have a double value that represents an epoch time but added the accuracy of a micro second. So a number like this:

```
double time_us=1628517578.547;
std::chrono::time_point time(time_us);
```

The above code doesn't;t work as I am getting the following error:

```
 no instance of constructor "time_point" matches the argument list
```

I need to do this conversion to get the millisecond of the day (number of Milliseconds that passed from the last night).

I plan to use the following code to get the required millisecond:

```
double sysTOH=time.hour*3600+time.min*60+time.sec+time.usec*1e-6;
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::chrono::` is a lot to write everywhere, so I'm going to assume:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
```

`time_point` is not a concrete type, [it is a class template](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.point):

```
template<class Clock, class Duration = typename Clock::duration> class time_point;
```

This means that you have to supply at least the first template parameter, and in your case, it is best to supply the second as well.

Your input, `time_ms`, has type `double`, and represents a count of `seconds`.  So start by creating a type that matches that description:

```
using ds = duration<double>;
```

`ds` is a `duration` with a `rep` of `double` and a `period` of `ratio<1>`.

Now it is handy to use a little of C++20 `<chrono>`.  Don't worry, if you don't have C++20, there is a [free, open-source, header-only preview of it that works with C++11/14/17](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
sys_time<ds> time{ds{time_ms}};
```

`sys_time` is a type alias supplied by ["date/date.h"](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) for the type:

```
time_point<system_clock, duration<double>>
```

I.e. a `time_point` based on `system_clock` using your custom `duration` type `ds` (double-based `seconds`).

One first converts the raw `double` to `double`-based `seconds`, and then to a `time_point` based on those `seconds`.

Next, it is best to convert to an integral-based `time_point` to find the time since midnight.  Your questions uses `microseconds` and `milliseconds` somewhat interchangeably.  So I am going to assume `milliseconds` for everything.  Change to `microseconds` if you need to.

```
auto tp = round<milliseconds>(time);
```

This takes the double-based `time_point` and converts it to an integral-based `time_point` that counts `milliseconds`.  `round` is used to avoid round-off error associated with double-based representations.  `round` is part of C++17 and later, but ["date/date.h"](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) will supply it for you in C++11/14.

The type of `tp` is `time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>`.

Next it is convenient to truncate `tp` to a precision of `days`:

```
auto td = floor<days>(tp);
```

`floor` is part of C++17 and later, but ["date/date.h"](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) will supply it for you in C++11/14.  `days` is a day-precision `duration`.  `td` is simply a count of days since the Unix epoch, and has type `time_point<system_clock, days>`.

One can also think of `td` as a time point to the beginning of the day.  So one can subtract it from `tp` to get the "time of day", or "time since midnight" UTC:

```
auto tod = tp - td;
```

`tod` has type `milliseconds` is the value is the number of `milliseconds` since midnight UTC.  If you need midnight defined by some time zone, then there's a little more work to do to take the UTC offset into account.  Your question is vague on this point.

Putting it all together:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    double time_ms=1628517578.547;
    using ds = duration<double>;
    sys_time<ds> time{ds{time_ms}};
    auto tp = round<milliseconds>(time);
    auto td = floor<days>(tp);
    auto tod = tp - td;
    std::cout << "tod = " << tod << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
tod = 50378547ms
```